# Finding the lowest coverience of 10 numbers out of 50 numbers in a text file

Tags: python, for-loop, math, finance, accounting

So basicly I have a text file with 50 numbers of coveriance, which fluctuate of roughly (plus minus) 1*10^{-6} from the number zero. I am trying to find 10 numbers from the data set which gives me the sum of thouse numbers closest to the number 0. Is it any way to do this in python by iterating thtough all the numbers and finding 10 numbers out of the 50 numbers which gives me number closest to zero? Hope this question makes sense :/

Comment: @SumnerEvans, I think you misread the question, the (signed) sum needs to come close to 0. Quite tricky I imagine

Comment: There's 50 choose 10 options of combining the values, which comes to 10,272,278,170 options for picking 10 values out of a hundred. Doable, but it'll take some time to calculate. You probably need something a bit smarter than iterating through all the options

Comment: Is it possible to do it in Excel with solver?

Comment: Oh, I see (facepalm). This is definitely NPC. @OP, you could use `itertools.combinations`, but as @Leander said, it's going to take a long time.

Comment: Haha, thought you missed something :P

Comment: @OP, I tried itertools.combinations for the fun of it, it has been running for 6 minutes now, and i'm giving up, if you don't mind waiting quite long to find the optimal value, you can use this approach, otherwise, I'd try something different.

Comment: No, Excel solver can't do it.  That maximizes one variable in an equation with otherwise fixed components.  If you want the exact minimum, you have to try all 10 billion combinations.  There are hacks, though.  Consider sorting the values and choosing the 10 that are closest to zero, +/-.  From there, you can try moving outward on the side with the imbalance.

Comment: @TimRoberts The way you said it, those hacks are not intended to find the exact minimum?

Comment: Right.  As several have said, the only way to find the absolute minimum is to try all 10 billion combinations.  It's an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts You can skip a lot of those 10 billion, though, see my updated answer.

Comment: This looks like an integer programming problem. Take a look at GLPK. There are several other packages which a web search would find.

Comment: @RobertDodier Does that work for non-integers like these numbers "which fluctuate of roughly (plus minus) 1*10^{-6} from the number zero"? (I don't know much about integer programming.)

Comment: @Manuel "Integer program" means the variables are integers. In fact the variables are just 0 or 1: 1 for including a number in the 10 selected, 0 for excluding. I forget whether the numbers must also be integers, but if floats are disallowed, one can just multiply through by the least common multiple of the denominators (either in base 2 or base 10) and get some integers to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.combinations`, should take less than an hour:

```
min(combinations(numbers, 10), key=lambda c: abs(sum(c)))
```

---

Idea for something faster: Split the numbers into two sets A and B with 25 numbers each. Take i numbers from A and 10-i numbers from B (try all i from 0 to 10).

For example when taking 3 numbers from A and 7 numbers from B, there are 25C3=2300 combinations from A and 25C7=480700 combinations from B. Sort those from B by sum, then go through those from A and binary search their negated sum in the combinations from B to find the best combination in B to combine with the combination from A.

For i>5, i.e., when you take more numbers from A than from B, and thus more combinations from A than from B, sort those from A instead and go through those from B and binary search in those from A.

It's more effort per combination, but it's far fewer combinations overall, so I think it would be faster:

```
>>> from math import comb

>>> comb(50, 10)
10272278170

>>> sum(comb(25, i) + comb(25, 10-i) for i in range(11))
14239032

>>> 10272278170 / 14239032
721.4168891537009
```

The creation and sorting of combinations with attached sums should take most of the time. Takes 30 seconds for doing that for i<6:

```
from random import random
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [random() * 2e-6 - 1e-6 for _ in range(50)]

B = numbers[25:]

for i in range(6):
    combs = [(sum(comb), comb) for comb in combinations(B, 10-i)]
    combs.sort()
```

So overall I think this solution will take about one minute.

Or we could first only find the best sum, and then in the end reconstruct the combination that produced that sum. The following takes about 4 seconds, so the whole real solution might take about 10 seconds:

```
for i in range(6):
    sums = list(map(sum, combinations(B, 10-i)))
    sums.sort()
```

Comment: 50 choose 10 is 10272278170, which seems excessive for a brute-force attempt.

Comment: @nanofarad They only asked for "any way", not for a fast way. And it should take less than an hour. Plus it can be useful for checking faster solutions for correctness. I have a faster solution in mind, but it's more work and it's late.

Comment: So had they done this instead of asking the question, they might already have the result by now :-D

Comment: @nanofarad Added my idea for something faster.